# How to change the apk file name (not app name) when generating a signed apk in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, apk

When I am generating a signed apk, the file name defaults to something like "com.companyname.projectname.apk". I would like to rename this file name while generating the apk via the code.

Comment: You can change the apk name while saving the apk in your destination folder or you can simply right click it and rename it

Comment: @Debs, I think you should accept one as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**1. One case**

If you want to change the name of your apk before you package your project, you can follow the steps just as Mukesh said.

1.right click your app -->`Properties`;

2.Switch to tab `Android Manifest`;

3.You will see the Package name just as follows,then you can modify the name of it.
[image]

**2. another case**

If you want to rename your apk file after you package your project,you can simply rename it  and save it to destination.

[image]

For more details, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio

1. Go to project properties by right clicking the android project.
2. Go to Android Manifest
3. Update Package name.